# What is the general integration of acceleration with respect to position?

Tags: integration

$$W = \int_{x_i}^{x_f} F_x dx + \int_{y_i}^{y_f} F_y dy \int_{z_i}^{z_f} F_z dz$$
same as saying 
$$E = m\int_{0}^{x_f} a_x dx + m\int_{0}^{y_f} a_y dy + m\int_{0}^{z_f} a_z dz$$
Using definitions of $a_{avg} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta {v^2}}{\Delta x}$ and maybe $a_{avg} = \frac{\Delta{v}}{\Delta{t}}$

Not sure how to do the integration to prove that this leads to $E = \frac{1}{2}m{v^2}$

Does the integral simply resolve to $m a x_f$ where $\Delta x$ and $x_f$ reduce leaving $\frac{1}{2}m\Delta {V^2}$?
Does it make sense that one could integrate something like that?
I wouldn't do $\int x dx = xx = x^2$
Maybe I'm missing something with fundamental definitions (I derived $a_{avg}$ from Galilean Kinematic Equations for uniform acceleration)

edit: I guess an easier question is: Does $\int{a}{dx}$ resolve to the same expression as $\int{a}{dt}$? If not, how are the integrations performed using formal notation?

Comment: Actually I should not use those definitions because that is average acceleration with respect to displacement. I want a more accurate function of acceleration with respect to displacement. What is the general form of acceleration with respect to position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int a\mathrm dx=\int a\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt=\int\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt=\frac12\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2+\text{const}\;.
$$

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow the last step. How is $$\int \frac{{d^2}x}{d{t^2}}dx$$ evaluated? I thought the anti-derivative of the second derivative of x with respect to time is just the first derivative of x with respect to time?

Comment: @Obliv: Write $v:=\mathrm dx/\mathrm dt$, then the last step is

$$
\int\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}v\mathrm dt=\frac12v^2+\text{const}\;,
$$

which you can verify by differentiating the right-hand side with respect to time. Your statement "the anti-derivative of the second derivative of $x$ with respect to time is just the first derivative of $x$ with respect to time" is correct if you form the anti-derivative with respect to time, but here we're looking for the anti-derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Oh I see. That is very clever use of differential notation. Okay looks solid thank you.

Comment: I think you could have just went from $\int adx$ to $\int {\frac{dv}{dt}}dx$ and then used the substitution of $dx = vdt$ Works either way.

Comment: @Obliv: Yes, you could.